# Mapbox LocationLayerPlugin 'Cannot reslove symbol'

Tags: android, mapbox

Creating a MapBox navigation application. I have been watching a YouTube tutorial on creating it. I have added `private LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin;` but it says `"Cannot Resolve symbol"`.

Added Dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.6.0'
```

I am not sure if it is related, but in my MapBox xml on my mainActivity i was getting errors saying `Unknown attribute mapbox`:

```
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="41.885"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-87.679"
    mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="@string/mapbox_style_light"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTilt="60"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12"
```

I have looked around everywhere trying to find a solution, with no luck.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after I posted this I found out I had missed adding a dependency

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.10.0'
```

Problem Solved.